# Bug on click back inside question

Tags: support, reputation

I have try to go into my question of stackoverflow, I have clicked questions, order by views, clicked the first question and if I click back inside Chrome my reputation changed from 6802 to 6772.

If I click again on another part return 6802.

Only if I click back inside the question my reputation change.

Is a bug right?

Comment: Probably caching. It's *always* caching...

Comment: But isn't changed of 30 points my reputation in this days.. and only with my question section @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: Rest assured your 6802 reputation points are there (I can see them). However, some pages are still stuck with stale cached data. Everything should be consistent again in a few minutes.

Comment: the home page and the questions page are the most heavily cached pages

Comment: If I click 'back', it generally goes back to the status when I first loaded the page. I have to refresh/reload the page to see the updates (extra answers, comments, resorted, changes in reputations, etc).  It's the way it works.

Comment: Chrome has some aggressive caching showing results from possibly days ago on a click back. SO is not the only site where this happens.

Comment: That is the browser cache - going back does re-fetch the page, it gets the locally cached version (possibly even from memory), which doesn't show the change in reputation. A proper refresh (F5) will.

Comment: It depends of your perspective,

The back/forward behavior is hard to trace and react to properly, there are lots of solutions out there to force certain chunks of JS in the site to be triggered when you navigate thru history, but your kind of *bug* is so annoying (and avoidable with a reload of the page) that many web developers says that correcting (or treating) these events do not pays off.

Comment: There should be a way for websites to disallow caching of their webpages. But even if there was, I hope the browsers will actually follow it...